# Python serial communication and run minicom command?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

Right now I am working on RPI 4, and connect UWB sensor to RPI through USB port

To run sensor, I need to type in terminal

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyAMC0
```

mincom will pop out. Then,

1. I need to press enter twice
2. type "nmt" and press enter
3. type enter twice
4. Then, type "lec" and enter to get data from sensor.

Is there way I can reduce this work into python code? So, I can just press run to get data from sensor.

I was able to get to the point where I type "minicom -D /dev/ttyAMC0" to open mincom connection through

```
os.system("minicom -D /dev/ttyAMC0")
```

However, I am looking for a way to run minicom command on python (command that I labels with number above).

Comment: This question may yield more help over at [Raspberry PI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange where folks can speak to both the programming and the physical set up to help troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to send command through minicom script using

```
minicom -S <script.txt>
```

and use the https://linux.die.net/man/1/runscript for ref.